# In python and appium,why can't use send_keys() to inputbox

Tags: python, appium, sendkeys

descr:when I used send_keys("xxx") to inputbox,I was told

> "**selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Cannot set the element to '15323423456'. Did you interact with the correct element?**"

what this coused by?
Is this plugin too high or too low? My XPath is not wrong
so I can't solve it,
would you like to help me solve this problem?thank you

CODES:

```
                    'newCommandTimeout' :'3000',
                        'unicodeKeyboard': True,
                        'resetKeyboard': True,
                        "automationName": "UiAutomator2"
                        }
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)

    def testchangeto_pageone(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10, 0.5).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@text='login']")))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@text='login']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']").send_keys("15323423456")
```

RESULTS:

[image]

Edition:

- selenium:3.1.4.1
- appium:1.15.1
- aapium-python-client:0.48

Answer (score 1):

I know what caused by,because of appium is too high.uninstalled and reinstalled 1.8.0